# JOOQ Code Generation Before Source Code Compilation

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle, jooq

I am using JOOQ code generation Tool for generating source code for my schema(MYSQL). I would like to generate source code every time I compile my Project. But I am not able to do it because when I run Code generation gradle Task, Compiler starts complaining about references of deleted source code.

Here is what I did:-

1. Created an Empty Spring boot Project.
2. Generated Source code using config xml(jooq.xml below) like [this](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/)
3. Triggered  Code Generation using a Gradle Task.

**Build.gradle**

```
task generateJooqDatabaseSource(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'org.jooq.util.GenerationTool'
    args = ['/jooq.xml']
    standardOutput = System.out
    errorOutput = System.err
}
```

4. Used the generated source code and wrote SQLs using JOOQ.

Everything is fine till here. But now I don't want to Push the generated Java Classes to my Project. I would like it to create every time when I compile my Project.

5. so lets delete the generated source code and re-generate it again(say for my Test environment)
6. But as soon as I run the Gradle Task `generateJooqDatabaseSource`
   it starts complaining about the generated code references.

> error: package autogenered.jooq.code.db.tables does not exist
>
> import autogenered.jooq.code.db.tables.Author;

Tried googling the problem and found suggestions to use plugins like  [flyway](https://github.com/wstrzalka/gradle-flyway-jooq-plugin), suggested [here](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual-single-page/#jooq-with-flyway)

***But I really don't want to add another plugin if it can be achieved easily without it.***

PS:- Just started to use Gradle, JOOQ from couple of days, apologies if answer is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Following Lines in build.gradle have done the tweak for me:

```
compileJava.dependsOn(generateJooqDatabaseSource)
generateJooqDatabaseSource.dependsOn = [processResources, processTestResources]
```

Intellij Specific configuration:-

Added gradle `build task` to be triggered every time I do

> make Project (Ctrl-F9)

or

> Re-build Project:

[image: IntelliJ gradle build task]